# Apple subscription purchase not getting title of product

Tags: swiftui

I am new using SwiftUI and I need to implement an in app subscription purchase.
I am trying to get product title to proceed purchase but nothing is returning. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI
import StoreKit

struct PlusView: View {
    @StateObject var storeManager = StoreManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(storeManager.products, id: \.self) { product in
            VStack {
                Text(product.localizedTitle)
                Button("Purchase", action: {
                    storeManager.purchase(product: product)
                })
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            storeManager.fetchProducts()
        }
        .environmentObject(storeManager)
    }
}

class StoreManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    @Published var products: [SKProduct] = []
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    }
    
    func fetchProducts() {
        let productIdentifiers: Set<String> = ["com.play.appname.productname"]
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
    
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.products = response.products
        }
    }
    
    func purchase(product: SKProduct) {
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    }
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                // Handle successful purchase
                UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "premium")
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            case .failed:
                // Handle purchase failure
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            case .restored:
                // Handle restored purchase
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong to get product info and finish purchase?
Thank you